# what would happen if kinetic energy never existed

Tags: energy

https://www.nationalgeographic.org/encyclopedia/hydroelectric-energy/
if you take a look at this site above it might be able to help you answer my question

Comment: Hydro-electrics is to do with converting gravitational potential energy into electricity, not kinetics per se. How does this question relate to worldbuilding? Please enjoy our [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work (we help writers and artists create *fictional worlds*). Voting to close as off-topic NAW.

Answer (score 6):

That depends on *why* kinetic energy never existed.

The easiest way to get rid of kinetic energy is to get rid of energy entirely. That would imply that the laws of physics do not have a continuous time translation symmetry. In the worst case, that could come about if the laws of physics changed randomly over time, producing a universe which wouldn't sustain life. In the best case, the laws of physics are still nicely well-behaved, but are perhaps based on something like a discrete-time cellular automaton at the lowest level. That would imply the existence of an absolute universal clock, which at some point would result in breaking relativity; i.e., if you want to keep the end-result universe looking as much like ours as possible, then just as Galilean mechanics fails at high speeds, requiring special relativity to make accurate predictions in the high speed regime, special relativity would itself fail in some high-speed limit, to be replaced with yet another more general theory.

The closest you could get to our universe without energy, however, is still probably not very close. The combination of conservation of energy and conservation of momentum is required to constrain a lot of problems to having a single physical solution. Without energy, a lot of "magical" possibilities open up (just think of how much stuff we could do if we weren't constrained by needing energy to do it!), but at the same time there is now a much wider range of possible outcomes for almost every physical interaction. Either you end up with a universe that is even *more* probabilistic than the quantum universe we live in, or you have to come up with some other new set of laws to replace conservation of energy in determining the outcome of mechanical interactions.

For one depiction of what a possible universe without energy (or momentum), but still supporting life, might look like, see *Schild's Ladder* by Greg Egan.

Comment: Why would no energy mean physical laws do not have continuous time translation symmetry?  A perfect vacuum universe (with no CMB nor dark energy) would have no energy, right?  But I wouldn't expect the laws of physics to be fundamentally different here.

Comment: There’s a lot of fantasy worlds that run on literal magic rather than the laws of physics. This hypothetical world might be one of them.

Comment: @cowlinator "Energy doesn't exist" and "the magnitude of energy is zero" are different things. Conserved quantities are associated with mathematical symmetries in physical laws, per Noether's Theorem. Energy happens to be the conserved quantity that you can derive from time translation symmetry. So if energy doesn't exist, there must not be time translation symmetry--because if there were such a symmetry, there would be energy!

Answer (score 4):

This cannot happen. Kinetic energy is, in essence, motion. Of particles, of objects, of physicist-style spherical cows---any motion is kinetic energy. Without kinetic energy, you end up with a completely motionless mass of matter at absolute zero, eternal and unchanging. There might be some quantum weirdness that I'm missing here, but without kinetic energy you have nothing.

Comment: are you a scientist

Comment: @hudson mcgaw chem major. not sure if that's close enough for you.

Comment: what is a chem major

Comment: @hudson mcgaw in college, studying chemistry in order to become a scientist specializing in it

Comment: can you send me your email so i can send you my powerpoint cause i need to know what changes to make because im making a powerpoint for high importance

Comment: I would take the first step that of doing a bit more research into terminology. Kinetic energy is probably the wrong term for what you're talking about (and it is related to hydroelectricity mostly in the sense that everything is related to kinetic energy). My recommendation would be to do a bit of research so that you can phrase the question better. Maybe also try other Stack Exchanges; depending on what you're after Physics or Engineering might be more helpful

Comment: So is it impossible, or is it nothing, or is it a completely and eternally motionless mass of matter at absolute zero?  It can't be all of these things.

Comment: @cowlinator i really dont know that is why i have asked that question in the first place

Comment: I'm asking Sol.

Comment: oh ok so sol is it impossible

Comment: In this universe, or any with similar rules, it is impossible. Basically, from the moment you impose this rule, nothing ever happens or changes, and everything is frozen at absolute zero. If you start pre-Big-Bang, you have whatever-there-was-before-the-Big-Bang, eternally.